# How can I use a variable's value in a variable name in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have an associative array and I'm making a switch function that starts like this:

`switch (Years['year'].StartDay) {`

The function that it's in passes a value called `year` and has a value in it, like this:

```
function CalendarData(year, month) {
    var Years = new Object();
    Years.['2013'].StartDay = 'Sunday';
    switch (Years['year'].StartDay) {
        case 'Sunday':
        this.Day = 1;
        break;
    }
}
```

I would like to make a new Object and get the data from the object, like this:

`var CalendarDay = new CalendarData('2013','February');`

The issue is it's not reading `Years['year'].StartDay`

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  Seems like a pretty legit question to me...

Comment: Some people downvote when a question which is asked shows a lack of understanding of the basic language structures.  In such a case, they prefer to simply tell someone to 'RTFM'.  Personally, I don't... everyone has to start somewhere, and it isn't like JavaScript is the simplest language to migrate to.  I would rather see someone's questions actually answered, even if it is simply a link to a manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Years['year'].StartDay
```

should be

```
Years[year].StartDay
```

And you also need to build the datastructure, there is no autovivification like Perl has:

```
var Years = new Object();
Years.['2013'].StartDay = 'Sunday';
```

should be

```
var Years = {};
Years[2013] = {};
Years[2013].StartDay = 'Sunday';
```

or (if none if this is flexible):

```
var Years = { '2013' : { StartDay : 'Sunday' } };
```

Comment: That's what I tried originally, but it didn't work. It tells me it can't read `StartDay` of undefined.

Comment: That suggests your array does not have a property with a key equal to `year`.

Comment: If I write `year = '2013';` immediately in front of the switch function, it still gives me that error.

Comment: @Jamil - Are you certain that `'2013'` is the value passed into your function as an argument? Sounds like you need to do some basic debugging.

Comment: I just realized I wrote it as `Years['2013'].StartDay = 'Sunday';` in the original, would that make the difference? I changed it and I have a different error, that `CalendarData` is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

remove the quotes you arent supposed to put them around a variable

instead of

```
Years['year'].StartDay
```

put

```
Years[year].StartDay
```

Answer (score 0):

I will have to assume that there is a lot of code not shown, here.

If that is the case, then the first period in:

```
Years.['2013'].Startday = 'Sunday';
```

... is, in the best case scenario, a typo.  It should probably appear like this:

```
Years['2013'].StartDay = 'Sunday';
```

However, it strikes me as a bit more than strange that you declare 'Years' as a bare, empty object the very line before you seem to assume this entire object structure existing beneath it.

The reference as written assumes, at minimum, that 'Years' is really an array, and that the index ['2013'] of that 'Years' array contains another object, and 'StartDay' is a member of the object that it contains.

None of this would work the way you intend it to, given that you just declared 'Years' as an empty object.

The simplest solution to directly answer the question which was asked is:

```
var Years = [];
Years['2013'] = 'Sunday';

switch(Years['2013'])
{
    case 'Sunday':
        // Do whatever here
        break;
    case 'Monday':
        // etc.
        break;
    // etc.
}
```

However, if you are actually trying to run the code you gave us, I might recommend reading up on the [JavaScript Object Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model)... it is quite powerful and flexible, but also very unlike most other languages.

This might be one of the sources of your problem.

I would recommend either [THIS](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/oopjs.shtml) or, if you prefer a physical book, as I do, the excellent "JavaScript: The Good Parts", which has become a standard for programmers coming to JavaScript from other languages.